# best method to support multiple orientations on iPAD with storyboards (no AutoLayout or AutoResizing)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I want to support landscape & portrait orientations on my iPAD app that uses a storyboard without getting involved into the intricacies of `Auto Layout` on `iOS6+` and `Auto Resizing` on `iOS 5` and earlier (since the app will support both iOS 5 & 6 so no `AutoLayout` is allowed here), what I thought of as a beginning point for the solution was the following:

creating two separate storyboards: `MainStoryboard-Portrait` & `MainStoryboard-Landscape`, when the current view controller (let's name it FirstViewController) is in portrait, and the user rotates the device to landscape, I `instantiate` a new `FirstViewController` from `MainStoryboard-Landscape` storyboard, and vice versa when the user rotates back to portrait. I did something like this in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method in `FirstViewController.m` :

```
  UIStoryboard *storyboard  = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard-Landscape" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  FirstViewController *VC =  [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC1"];
  self.view = VC.view;
```

but the following crash happens on iOS6+: `A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time!`, tried it also on iOS5 there will be no crash but the rotation does not work properly: window bounds rotates but the view itself keeps as is.

How to get this working on both iOS 5 & 6 ? or if there is another better method please provide me with a working code sample for it and i will award you a bounty of 50 points.

Answer (score 8):

if you really don't wish to use auto layout, doing this in a single .storyboard can still be done by having an `IBOutlet (weak, nonatomic) UIView* portraitView` and an `IBOutlet (weak, nonatomic) UIView* landscapeView`.  create each view as a subview of the main `view` for `FirstViewController` in .storyboard.

then in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, perform the following:

```
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation))
    {
        self.portraitView.hidden = NO;
        self.landscapeView.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        self.portraitView.hidden = YES;
        self.landscapeView.hidden = NO;
    }
```

when working on your views in .storyboard, you can see each subview a little better by checking/unchecking the `hidden` flag in the right sidebar.

then, another advantage of this is that if you have some views that look ok regardless of orientation, you don't have to maintain a separate storyboard file and scene for them.

Comment: it still a design headache for complex UI views + i think there will be a bigger memory footprint loading two views at the same time for each scene.

Comment: if you have a storyboard with portrait and landscape views with many view controllers, xcode will eat all memory even if the memory was more than 8 GB

Answer (score 1):

Auto layout really is the way to go. As soon as you've got two storyboards you've got a maintenance and consistency headache — if you want the portrait and landscape user experience to be the same. If you specifically want them to be different for a reason, then two storyboards is appropriate.

Comment: auto layout is very complicated when you start working with a complex UI project

Comment: It can be, but the XCode UI designer hides a lot of that complexity.

Comment: This isn't a good answer, as he said he wants to be able to support pre iOS 6. By supporting only iOS 6, you effectively kill a large portion of the user base. iOS 6 adoption is good, but it isn't THAT good.

Comment: @jmstone : yes supporting iOS 6 only is sure killing a portion of user base but the adoption rate is superb ... 96% of anything is a very good adoption.

Comment: 96% now, in August. It wasn't 96% in January when I wrote the origin comment.